# Order of a product of two cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutations

Is it true or false?

If $a$ is a permutation that is an $m$-cycle and $b$ is the permutation that is $n$-cylce then order of $ab = \operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: Well, which is it?

Comment: If you want to know if it is  true or false... It is true(for disjoint cycles)!! If you want to know why, please try explaining here what you have tried...

Comment: What is the order of $(12)(123)$ in $S_3$? Hint: $S_3$ is not cyclic.

Answer (score 5):

If the cycles are disjoint, your statement is true.

For non-disjoint cycles, a counterexample is given by
$$
\operatorname{ord}((12)(23)) = \operatorname{ord}((123)) = 3.
$$

Comment: is there a general formula for the order of the product of non-disjoint cycles?

Comment: @OmarShehab: Well, it depends on the overlap. What you can always do is transform the product into disjoint cycle representation (like in my example) and then read off the order as the lcm of the cycle lengths.

Comment: yes, I can definitely work it out after converting it into a disjoint cycle. But is there a general formula which takes the information about the non-disjoint cycles (length, number of overlapping elements, etc.)  as inputs and give the order?

Comment: @OmarShehab: I don't know about such a formula. A general formula would not only need the size of the overlap, but also the exact positions of the overlapping elements and their order as input data. So I doubt that there is a general formula better than "write the product in disjoint cycle decomposition and take the lcm of the cycle lengths". In special cases, it might be possible to come up with something.